# HasMany objects disappearing after reloading

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models, `User` and `Project`:

```
App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
                name: DS.attr('string'),
                url: DS.attr('string'),
                user: DS.belongsTo('user')
            });

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
                name: DS.attr('string'),
                projects: DS.hasMany('project')
            });
```

I am using local storage for Ember Data to store the users and projects. I am populating the users and projects using AJAX calls in the `IndexController`:

```
'createUser' : function(){
                            var name = this.get('newUser');
                            if(!name){
                                return;
                            }

                            var that = this;

                            Ember.$.getJSON('<apiUrl>).then(function(data){
                                var user = that.store.createRecord('user', data);
                                user.save();
                                that.set('newUser', '');
                                Ember.$.getJSON(<apiUrl>/projects').then(function(data){
                                        var length = data.length;
                                        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
                                            data[i].id = data[i].name;
                                            data[i].user_id = data.id;
                                            var project = that.store.createRecord('project', data[i]);
                                            project.save();
                                            user.get('projects').addObject(project);
                                        }

                                        user.save();
                                });
                            });
                        },

        }
```

When I go to the URL for the user, the projects display correctly. However, when I reload the page, the projects disappear and are not displayed anymore. My view for the projects is this (inside of the user template):

```
   {{#each projects}}
            <div class="row">
             <a {{bind-attr href="url"}}>{{name}}</a>
            </div>
            {{else}}
              <p>No projects loaded</p>
          {{/each}}
```

Am I doing something incorrectly that is causing the projects to not get reloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this [here](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/pull/26). In order to get this working, I needed to reopen the `JSONSerializer`:

```
DS.JSONSerializer.reopen({
    serializeHasMany : function(record, json, relationship) {
        var key = relationship.key;

        var relationshipType = DS.RelationshipChange.determineRelationshipType(
                record.constructor, relationship);

        if (relationshipType === 'manyToNone'
                || relationshipType === 'manyToMany'
                || relationshipType === 'manyToOne') {
            json[key] = Ember.get(record, key).mapBy('id');
        }
    }
});
```